# remove the filtered line from the file using scala fs2 file streaming

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, scala-streams

how to remove the `filtered` lines from the current streaming file using [fs2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) and get the count of filtered lines as the return type?

ex: If the `old.txt` contains strings separated by a newline (\n):

```
 john
 sam
 chen
 yval
 ....
```

and `val myList = List("chen","yval")`.

```
def converter[F[_]](implicit F: Sync[F]): F[Unit] =
  io.file.readAll[F](Paths.get("testdata/old.txt"), 4096)
    .through(text.utf8Decode)
    .through(text.lines)
    .filter(s => myList.contains(s))//remove this from the old file and write to new file
    .intersperse("\n")
    .through(text.utf8Encode)
    .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get("testdata/new.txt")))
    .compile.drain

// at the end of the universe...
val u: Unit = converter[IO].unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [observe method](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/0.10.5/fs2-core_2.12-0.10.5-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream$$InvariantOps.html) of the `Stream` class.

You are looking for a function `def converter[F[_]: Sync]: F[Int]`, 
which produces a computation `F[Int]` whose result (of type `Int`) is the number of filtered lines, and whose effect is to write those lines to the output file.  To follow a plumbing analogy, you want to *feed* your filtered stream to two outputs, one for the result, and one for the effect. 
You can  do this using the function [observe](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/0.10.5/fs2-core_2.12-0.10.5-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream$$InvariantOps.html), defined as

```
def observe(sink: Sink[F, O])(implicit F: Effect[F], ec: ExecutionContext): Stream[F, O]
```

A `Sink[F,O]` is an alias for a function `Stream[F, O] => Stream[F, Unit]`. In your case, the *sink* is the part of your code that writes your filtered stream into the output file:

```
def writeToFile[F[_]: Sync]: Sink[F, String] = 
  _.intersperse("\n")
  .through(text.utf8Encode)
  .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get("testdata/new.txt")))
```

The other output is to reduce, or rather fold,

```
  def converter[F[_]](implicit F: Effect[F], ec: ExecutionContext): F[Int] = 
    io.file.readAll[F](Paths.get("testdata/old.txt"), 4096)
      .through(text.utf8Decode)
      .through(text.lines)
      .filter(s => myList.contains(s))
      .observe(writeToFile[F])
      .compile
      .fold[Int](0)( (c, _) => c+1)
}
```

*Note*: for this solution you need to restrict the type-class of `F` to be `Effect`, and you need to use an `ExecutionContext`. The `fold` is defined in the [`ToEffect`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.12/0.10.5/fs2-core_2.12-0.10.5-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream$$ToEffect.html) class.